# css on focus change another div's styling

Tags: html, css, svg, sass, focus

I want the svg to change the fill color when a user have focus on the input. 
But I don't understand how to write the css to make it happen. 
Added Html and css for you to check out! I'm using scss for the css.

```
<div class="search">
    <svg width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 88 88" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <g id="Symbols" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill-rule="evenodd">
            <g id="Icon-Search" fill="#b3b3b3" fill-rule="nonzero">
                <path d="M86.829,81.172 L64.128,58.471 C69.055,52.312 72,44.5 72,36 C72,16.118 55.883,0 36,0 C16.118,0 0,16.118 0,36 C0,55.882 16.118,72 36,72 C44.5,72 52.312,69.054 58.471,64.127 L81.172,86.828 C81.953,87.609 82.977,88 84,88 C85.024,88 86.048,87.609 86.829,86.828 C88.391,85.267 88.391,82.733 86.829,81.172 Z M36,64 C20.536,64 8,51.464 8,36 C8,20.536 20.536,8 36,8 C51.465,8 64,20.536 64,36 C64,51.464 51.465,64 36,64 Z" id="Shape"></path>
            </g>
         </g>
      </svg>

      <input class="input inputSearchField" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
  </div> 



.input{
    width: 250px;
    height: 35px;
    padding-left: 16px;
    font-weight: 700;
    background-color: $white-color;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid $lighter-gray;
    font-size: 16px;
    outline:none;
    transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    &::placeholder {
        color: $light-gray;
    }
    &:focus {
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px #64e469;
        border: 1px solid #64e469;
    }
}
.search { 
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 270px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .search svg { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    right: 22px;
    fill: $lighter-gray;
  }
```

Comment: We'll need the relevant HTML as well in order to properly assist

Comment: What does your HTML / SVG look like?

Comment: If the svg and input tag are siblings, you can do it by input:focus ~ svg {}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this <kbd>[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/xhynk/pen/qYoopB)</kbd>. You'll need to move your input *before* your SVG, otherwise you'll have to use some JavaScript to do this, because CSS doesn't have a "look behind" selector of any kind. Even the [General Sibling Combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) only looks ahead of the current selector target.

If you move the input first, you can just do:

```
.input:focus + svg #Icon-Search {
  fill: #64e469;
}
```

If you *do* want to keep the current structure, the JavaScript would look something like on this <kbd>[Demo](https://codepen.io/xhynk/pen/jxzzxK)</kbd>

```
let search  = document.getElementsByClassName('inputSearchField');
let svgFill = document.getElementById('Icon-Search');

search[0].onfocus = function(){ svgFill.style.fill = '#64e469'; }
search[0].onblur  = function(){ svgFill.style.fill = '#b3b3b3'; }
```

You can see it's a fair bit more tedious!

Comment: My pleasure! I updated the answer as well to show what it would look like if you kept the current structure and used JavaScript as well, as a reference. Glad to help!

Comment: Cool :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering that you have a html like it:

```
<div class="search">
  <input class="input" />
  <svg />
</div>
```

Your css can be something like this:

```
.input:focus + svg { ... }
```

If `svg` comes before `input`, then you can use `~` instead `+`